# Possible to a flexible document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

For something like this,

```
{
  {"Dog", "Charlie", "male"},
  {"Dog", "Mimi", "female", "young and pretty"},
  ...
  {"Pig", "Foo"}
}
```

It can't be a BsonDocument because it must be a collection of BsonElement (a value pair). How to define and store them in a MongoDB's document? Say C#

Answer (score 1):

Mongodb documents consist of key value pairs. If you want to store a list of strings in a document you can create an array:

```
var myDoc = {
   stringElements: ["Dog", "Charlie", "male"] 
}
```

Comment: how to add this array into BsonDocument dynamically? for example this not working: `BsonDocument d = new BsonDocument(); d.Add({"string", ["Dog", "Charlie", "male"]);`